# Uploading to DB from Excel with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I have this python script that uses pandas read an excel sheet then to update a sqlite db it works perfectly just wondering if I can speed it up as I am at about 70k lines

```
"""
Created on Thu Aug  1 14:11:01 2019

@author: Shane Pitts
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import pandas as pd
import shutil

#Takes DB File path then creates connection to it
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    return None
#updates reported table    
def update_dupi_reported(conn, dupi, userID, op):

    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE reported SET dupi = :dupi WHERE userID = :userID AND operator = :op",
                       {'dupi':dupi, 'userID':userID, 'op':op})
#updates blocked table
def update_dupi_blocked(conn, dupi, userID, op):

    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("UPDATE blocked SET dupi = :dupi WHERE userID = :userID AND operator = :op",
                       {'dupi':dupi, 'userID':userID, 'op':op})
def Count():
    #Creates a dataframe with the Excel sheet information
    df = pd.DataFrame()    
    df = pd.read_excel("/root/Shane_db/Count.xlsx")

    #Assigns a variable to the DataBase
    database = "/root/Shane_db/db.db"

    # create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    #Runs through the DataFrame once for reported
    for i in df.index:
        userID = df['userID'][i]
        dupi = df['dupi'][i]
        op = df['operator'][i]
        print(i)
        with conn:
            update_dupi_reported(conn, dupi, userID, op)
            #Runs through a Second time for blocked
    for x in df.index:
        userID = df['userID'][x]
        dupi = df['dupi'][x]
        op = df['operator'][x]
        print(x)
        with conn:
            update_dupi_blocked(conn, dupi, userID, op)

    shutil.copy("/root/Shane_db/db.db", "/var/www/html/site/db.db")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Count()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I don't mean this in any rude way at all would this be a better title?

Comment: It is better... though keywords like [tag:pandas] and [tag:excel] are not as beneficial since the question has some of those as tags... if you had a description of how the data is used (e.g. for some type of report) that could help add clarity for reviewers (either in the title and/or description)